# Array to String Issue when Deleting Data

Tags: php

Been working on a small project for myself and have gotten lost in this part

```
if(empty($_REQUEST['ID'])) {
    echo "tuks";
} else {
    $id = $_REQUEST["ID"];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM list WHERE ID = $id";
}
```

Upon form submit, I'm getting the following error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion

Searched a couple of threads with no luck.

Comment: Apparently `$_REQUEST['ID']` is an array, despite your expectation that it's a string. It's not obvious from this code how that happened, though.

Comment: run `var_dump($_REQUEST["ID"]);`

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(17)

Comment: then `$_REQUEST["ID"][0]` is probably the string you want. i dont like using request, as you dont know which of ( $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE. ) is the source, better to use  $_GET or $_POST or $_COOKIE instead

Comment: The error has already occurred in code previous to the code you're showing here. Figure out how you're assigning values to `$_REQUEST['ID']`. Is this input from a form, or something else?